# A simple issue on my IMDB movie application on Android

Tags: java, android

I am making an android application using IMDB open-source api (My movie api).

Features are:
when user search a particular movie they got the list in list view. If they click on a list it shows full details of the movie. 
User also can add any movie to favourite list and also can delete it.

Everything works fine. BUT THE APPLICATION FORCE CLOSES IF ANY FIELD IS MISSING FOR A MOVIE ON IMDB DATABASE LIKE MOVIE LANGUAGE OR DURATION ETC.

I have tried if- else syntax but not worked. If have any suggestion please let me know. I will be thankful to you.

Here is my code:

ImageProvider Ip = new ImageProvider();

```
    final String Title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    final String story = getIntent().getStringExtra("story");
    final String actors = getIntent().getStringExtra("actors");
    final String lang = getIntent().getStringExtra("lang");
    final String Id = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
    final String duration = getIntent().getStringExtra("time");
    final String directBy = getIntent().getStringExtra("director");
    final String year1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("year");
    final String src = getIntent().getStringExtra("img");

    Log.v("src", src);

    title.setText(Title);
    details.setText(story);
    cast.setText(actors);
    language.setText(lang);
    mid.setText(Id);
    time.setText(duration);
    Director.setText(directBy);
    year.setText(year1);
    VImg.setImageBitmap(Ip.fetchImage(src));
```

Comment: Can u show your bit of code

Comment: thank you guys for your quick reply. I got some another process. let me try this first. if bugs continue i will show you the code... :)

Comment: Bug is solved. used if clause...:)